# Background Image not displaying on iPhone

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

How do I make the background image display on iPhone as it displays on Android?

**HTML**

```
<div class="bgimg-1">    
    <div class="hometoptext ">
        <h1 class="text-center">
            Africa's First Online Business Lender
        </h1>
        <div>
            <h3 class="thin">Grow faster with South Africa's most innovative online funder</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="applyNow()">APPLY NOW</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-arrow text-center">

    </div>
</div>
```

Background Image not  displaying on iPhone

**CSS**

```
.bgimg-1 {
    background-image: url("img/main_pic2.png");
    color: white;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-color: #999;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
}
```

Image on Android:

[image]

Image on iPhone:

[image]

Comment: how does it relate to Android?

Comment: @VladMatvienko Because it is displaying on an Android, I guess.

Comment: I love how we edit for the sake of editing @VladMatvienko

Comment: Just a suggestion, iOS seems to have partial support for `background-attachment: fixed` - http://www.caniuse.com/#search=background-attachment

Answer (score 0):

- iOS Safari has buggy behavior with `background-size: cover;` +
  `background-attachment: fixed`;
- Safari (OS X and iOS) and Chrome do not support background-size: 100%
  px; in combination with SVG images, it leaves them at the
  original size while other browsers stretch the vector image correctly
  while leaving the height at the specified number of pixels.
- iOS Safari has buggy behavior with `background-size: cover;` on a
  page's body.
- macOS Safari 10 is having frame rate issue with `background-size`.
- Android 4.3 browser and below are reported to not support percentages
  in `background-size`

Ref : [Link](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size)

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to this issue is still a pure CSS Fallback

[CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) has three great methods, the latter two are fall backs for when CSS3's cover doesn't work.

**HTML**

```
<img src="img/main_pic2.png" id="bg" alt="">
```

**CSS**

```
#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 

  /* Preserve aspect ratio */
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The background image is not supported on iOS devices.
Proof link: https://caniuse.com/?search=background-url